# Apply function with two factored vectors of different length

Tags: r

I have a function which takes two vectors that are of differing lengths. The function is fed monthly data from a vector of daily data spanning multiple years. So far I have been "manually" `split()`ting the data and running a loop over the months, more or less like so:

```
f1 <- as.factor(substring(names(data1), 1, 7))
s1 <- split(data1, f1)
f2 <- as.factor(substring(names(data2), 5, 9)) # the objects specify dates differently 
s2 <- split(data2, f2)

res <- vector("list", 12)
for (i in 1:12) {
  res[[i]] <- my_func(s1[[i]], s2[[i]])
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this? The `apply()` family of functions don't seem to do the trick - `lapply()` takes only one list, for example, and nesting lists in a master list doesn't work either; `mapply()` takes multiple arguments but goes through the elements one by one while I need to process multiple elements at a time.

Comment: Your loop is equivalent to `res <- Map(my_func, s1, s2)`

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of your data using `dput()` or atleast some data with a similiar data structure.

Comment: @DarrenTsai Aaaaaaaah right. `split()` gives one level of indirection (it returns a list of vectors) so that does the trick. Make it an answer and you have my vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Map`(equivalent to `mapply(..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE)`) to apply a function over multiple list or vector arguments.

```r
res <- Map(my_func, s1, s2)
```